# SQL Server GROUP BY bigger than

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I query and have a table with the following sample data

```
SELECT  tb1.ID ,
        tb2.TypeID ,
        tb2.Name
FROM    tb1
        INNER JOIN tb2 ON tb1.ID = tb2.ID
WHERE   tb1.Status = 1
GROUP BY tb1.ID ,
         tb2.TypeID ,
         tb2.Name

ID  | TypeID | Name|
======================
11  | 1      | A  | 
19  | 1      | A  | 
10  | 2      | A  |
5   | 1      | B  | 
4   | 2      | B  | 
20  | 1      | C  | 
21  | 1      | C  |
```

I'd like to create a query that shows the ID for each distinct TypeID +Name more than 1, e.g.

```
ID  |
=====
11  | 
19  | 
20  |
21  |
```

Can anyone give me a little help? Thanks.

Comment: but in your example there is no 5 or 4 ? aB and 2 B are also needed by the logic u provided.

Comment: @JanWalczak - because the `(TypeID, Name)` combination `(1,A)` occurred more than once, we get 11 and 19. Because `(1,C)` occurred more than once, we get 20 and 21. No other combination of those two columns occurred more than once.

Comment: True, my mistake, You need those that are used more than once.

Comment: I added answer that i think should work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this,

```
SELECT tb1.ID
FROM tb1
INNER JOIN tb2 ON tb1.ID = tb2.ID
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT tb2.TypeID
        ,tb2.NAME
    FROM tb1
    INNER JOIN tb2 ON tb1.ID = tb2.ID
    WHERE tb1.STATUS = 1
    GROUP BY tb2.TypeID
        ,tb2.NAME
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) tb3 ON tb3.typeid = tb2.typeid
    AND tb3.NAME = tb2.NAME
WHERE tb1.STATUS = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a subquery that will select all records grouped by those two fields and having 2 and more occurrence after that grouping.

```
SELECT tb1.ID FROM tb1 INNER JOIN tb2 ON tb1.ID = tb2.ID INNER JOIN (
    SELECT tb2.TypeID ,tb2.name FROM tb1
    INNER JOIN tb2 ON tb1.ID = tb2.ID WHERE tb1.status = 1
    GROUP BY tb2.TypeID ,tb2.name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) temp ON temp.typeid = tb2.typeid
    AND temp.name = tb2.Name
WHERE tb1.status = 1
```

Comment: Nó hoạt động. cảm ơn cho câu trả lời.